# How to expect a Date format by using toMatchObject() in jest

Tags: node.js, datetime, jestjs, timestamp, ts-jest

I am trying to verify wether one of the entry in an object is in ISO timestamp.
Using the `expect.any($type)`

I have tried using Date, ISO_8601, and timestamp. How can I find what is the correct way to define the type here ? Or what should I do to customize one ?

[This is a what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFqCF.png)

Answer (score 1):

As per the jest documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject

> Use .toMatchObject to check that a JavaScript object matches a subset
> of the properties of an object. It will match received objects with
> properties that are not in the expected object.

in your case properties are there, but their values are not the same, so the test will fail.

Here is my solution, its a combination of **objectContaining** and **stringMatching**

```
const actual = {
  time: '2022-08-15T13:43:24.376Z'
};
const isoPattern = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/;
expect(actual).toEqual(
  expect.objectContaining({ time: expect.stringMatching(isoPattern) })
);
```

let me know if is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toBeDateString` from [`jest-extended` matchers](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/string/#tobedatestringstring):

```
const matchers = require('jest-extended');
expect.extend(matchers);

it('should be a valid date', async () => {
    const time = '2023-08-10T02:27:20Z';
    expect(time).toBeDateString();
})
```

To use with snapshot [property matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#property-matchers):

```
it('should match schema snapshot', async () => {
    const payload = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', time: '2023-08-10T02:27:20Z'};
    expect(payload).toMatchSnapshot({
      time: expect.toBeDateString(),
    });
})
```

This will generate a jest snapshot that would match a dynamic timestamp:

```
exports[`should match schema snapshot 1`] = `
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "time": toBeDateString<>,
}
`;
```